# Universal Property of the Ring of Quotients.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, universal-property

Let $R$, $R'$ be commutative rings with multiplicative subsets $S, S'$ and the corresponding ring homomorphisms $\phi, \phi'$ into their respective ring of fractions. 
Prove that for any ring homomorphism $f : R \rightarrow R',$ which maps $S$ into $S'$, there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\tilde{f} : S^{-1}R \rightarrow S'^{-1}R'$ such that $\tilde{f} \circ \phi = \phi' \circ f.$
 \begin{array}{cc}  
 R & \xrightarrow{f} & R' \\
  \downarrow{\phi} & & \downarrow{\phi'} \\ 
 S^{-1} R & \xrightarrow{\tilde{f}}
     & S'^{-1} R'           
\end{array}

Also describe the image and the kernel of $\tilde{f}$  in terms relative to $f$.

**Idea:** I want to show this using the the universal property of the ring of quotients $S^{-1} R$, I am just not sure how to put all the pieces together.  Any help/hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $\phi' \circ f$ maps each element of $S$ to an invertible element of $S'^{-1} R'$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks! I see it now